# How do I build a 4x2 Piston Gate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have been searching the Internet searching for the solution, but I have yet to see it...

Just to clarify I am NOT looking for...

[image]

I want to solution to the following gate...

[image]

The Gate is very limited to the space above the opening as I can not place any redstone wiring above the Gate's Opening.  I'd prefer the solution opens the gate Side to Side.  I already know how to open it Up & Down.
I was thinking the solution would include the use of Sand and or Gravel.  as you could force it upward and let it fall when the pistons are contracted.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on how the gate should open? Sideways? Up/down?

Comment: @JonK No there aren't any restrictions to how the gate should open...

Comment: I didn't think of having it open up/down... I'll try that thanks @JonK

Comment: The x-axis comes first, followed by the y-axis, just like the order of the alphabet. That's a 4x2 piston gate you have there.

Comment: I don’t know if it’s even possible for that kind of gate to open from both sides. As far as my redstone understanding goes, sticky pistons cannot pull multiple blocks. You might as well open the gate up and down as you said. Have you seen this gate on a server or in a YouTube video?

Comment: @GhostCoder20 No I was building a Castle on survival and I was wondering if it was possible to open it from the X Axis...

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's *not* possible, but it would definitely be *insanely* complicated, as you would need specificly timed circuits, various types of double/triple piston extenders, and whatnot. The size of this contraption may be bigger than your castle itself (if it's not the biggest one).

Comment: It is definitly easy to do just with a few restrictions, keyword: Slime Blocks. As long as they touch nothing but your gate or blocks that can't be moved, you can open gates which are bigger than 2 blocks.

Comment: Started working on a solution, this miiight be somewhat feasible to do, with a couple caveats: the wall will need to be at least 5 blocks thick, the 'door' will need to be inset by 2 blocks, rather than the one shown, and there may need to be obsidian 'rails' on either side of the door at the top and bottom so allow slime blocks to slide along while only grabbing the granite door when pushed/pulled. and there's going to need to be a lot of room underneath for redstone.

Comment: [sidenote: as one might expect, this is considerably easier and more compact if Command Blocks were to be used]

Comment: Do you want it opening sideways for visual reasons, or because of space constrictions?

Comment: I've got [a working model](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tMXe5.jpg). The redstone might be a little sloppy in places, but I got it working and then feared adjusting anything might throw off the timing. I'll probably work on getting better screenshots and/or circuit blueprints and post an answer later tonight.

Comment: @colorfusion Yes, it is a yes to both because I would have to redo the entire Northern wall if I was to have redstone wired above the Gate's opening, and it would look cooler opening sideways.

Comment: I was thinking the solution would be simpler if Gravel or Sand was used, because then you would only need to open it from the bottom.

Comment: Yeah is there a reason other than you being totally awesome for figuring out how to do this that you are against command blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I had to end up doing is make the gate out of gravel (*any type of falling block would work*) and have 2 pistons (*the bottom being a sticky Piston*) push up the gravel and contract as so...

***Contracted (Unpowered)***

[image: Contracted]

***Extented (Powered)***

[image: Extended]

I just found this was the easiest way for the gate to work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a vertical 4x4 design and rotate it 90 degrees?

Comment: Wow, now I feel stupid not thinking of that earlier...

Comment: @Eisler485 Happens to the best of us

Answer (score -1):

You could make the door out of sand or gravel by placing a piston with slime block facing upwards. You could probably bounce the sand/gravel high enough to run under before it falls back to the slime block, right back where it started. If this helped please put this as a accepted answer, thanks :)

Comment: You had me there til you said bounce the sand... I was thinking the same track you were on, but I was thinking about having a Sticky Piston push up and Extended piston, then contracting letting the sand fall two blocks.

Comment: The only thing that is keeping this from working is that the Sand block that is touching the Slime block doesn't bounce, the sand is stuck to the slime block.